# Android Add Textview in java file, not XML

Tags: android, textview

I need to be able to add a textview to my app with code, not using the XML or Graphic interface...
I have an imageview, but cannot figure out how to modify it to get a Textview (Im new to Android)...

Here is my imageview code:

```
//Add view using Java Code
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(AndroidAddViewActivity.this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams 
= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);

mainLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("the text");
LayoutParams textViewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textView.setLayoutParams(textViewLayoutParams);
mainLayout.addView(textView);
```

Comment: what might be the data type for the mainLayout variable (View) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with the following:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("the text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add like

```
TextView nameHere = new TextView(this);
nameHere.setText("your text here");
```

This is just simple line of code you can modify it to do much more :)